# Data is not part of enum values

Tags: python, postgresql, ubuntu, flask, enums

I'm currently trying to display a table which contains differents types of data (mainly string). But I have a problem to display my enumeration data value. Here is some codes :

```
def user_list(page=1)
    fields = OrderedDict([
        ("name", {"name": "Name", "size": 2}),
        ("surname", {"name": "Surname", "size": 2}),
        ("rights", {"enum": User_Rights, "name": "User Rights", "size": 2}),
        #few other fields
    ])

    default_sort = "name"
    pages = listItem(User, default_sort, fields, page) #error here
    #few code after
```

`User` and Enumeration definitions :

```
class Rights_Enum(Enum):
    admin = "Administrateur"
    user = "Utilisateur"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value

    @classmethod
    def as_list(drt):
        out = [[-1, ""]]
        return out + [[x.name, x.value] for x in drt]

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "utilisateur"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    #some others data
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    surname = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    rights = db.Column(db.Enum(Rights_Enum), nullable=False)

    #few intern functions

    def has_rights(self, *rights):
        for right in rights:
            if right not in self.rights:
                return False
        return True

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.nom
```

`listItem` function definition :

```
def listItem(
    ItemClass, default_sort, fields, page, filters=None, join=None, itemperpage=15
):
    query = ItemClass.query
    if join:
        query = query.outerjoin(join)
    if filters:
        for f in filters:
            query = query.filter(f)

    query = add_sort(ItemClass, default_sort, fields, query)
    pages = query.paginate(page, itemperpage) #error here

    return pages
```

Here you can read my error when I try to access `user_list` function :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/damadam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/damadam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/damadam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/damadam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/damadam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/damadam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/damadam/Documents/project/Utils/templated.py", line 15, in decorated_function
    ctx = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/damadam/Documents/project/Routes/utilisateur.py", line 150, in utilisateur_liste
    pages = listItem(User, default_sort, fields, page)
  File "/home/damadam/Documents/project/Utils/ListItem.py", line 69, in listItem
    pages = query.paginate(page, itemperpage)
  File "/home/damadam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 491, in paginate
    items = self.limit(per_page).offset((page - 1) * per_page).all()
  File "/home/damadam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2773, in all
    return list(self)
  File "/home/damadam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 98, in instances
    util.raise_from_cause(err)
  File "/home/damadam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/home/damadam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 187, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/damadam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 79, in instances
    rows = [proc(row) for row in fetch]
  File "/home/damadam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 79, in <listcomp>
    rows = [proc(row) for row in fetch]
  File "/home/damadam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 508, in _instance
    loaded_instance, populate_existing, populators)
  File "/home/damadam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 608, in _populate_full
    dict_[key] = getter(row)
  File "/home/damadam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py", line 1507, in process
    value = self._object_value_for_elem(value)
  File "/home/damadam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py", line 1427, in _object_value_for_elem
    '"%s" is not among the defined enum values' % elem)
LookupError: "Utilisateur" is not among the defined enum values
```

P.S : I'm working on an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS machine, using Flask and PostgreSQL as database. If you need to have a few HTML code, I can provide them